# Poisson counting process parameter

Tags: estimators, poisson-process

Two quick questions:

1. What's the maximum likelihood estimator of the parameter of an homogeneous Poisson counting process?
2. To estimate $\lambda$ I'm currently using number of events/total time, $N(t)/\Delta t$. What distribution does this statistic follow?

Comment: You obviously mean a homogeneous poisson process right? Do I understand (2) in the sense that you just count the number of events over some time interval and this is done repeatedly?

Comment: Yes, homogeneous. I will edit it. In (2) I have a running experiment (working under the hypothesis that the process is homogeneous so lambda does not change). The rate is constantly updated, but at some particular $t$ I use $N(t)/\Delta t$.

Comment: (2) is MLE of (1). I don't think there's a well known distribution for (2).

Comment: Ok, thank you. Any moments known, std deviation, or empirical model of the distribution? Or reference?